# onchange Submit Form with Page Anchor

Tags: javascript, php, html, onchange, form-submit

Using something like this code is there anyway of passing a html anchor to jump to a particular place in the page when it has been submitted?

```
onChange="document.form2.submit()"
```

Im using this code above for a dropdown menu which submits after selection, but i also need it to pass a page anchor.. is this doable?

many thanks

ps The anchor will depend on which dropdown menu was used. There are, for example, around 40 dropdown menus in a page.. so when you get over 20 you have to keep scrolling down to select the next one.. this is why i need the page, after submitting, to jump to the last dropdown used... Hope this makes sense.

Comment: For this purpose, you should do ajax instead of page reload.

Comment: @RaviHirani Why Ajax? What's the advantage of using Ajax here? Having an anchor in the form's action attribute should work as well

Comment: Is the page anchor always the same or does it depend on what has been selected in the dropdown?

Comment: The anchor will depend on which dropdown menu was selected. There are for example around 40 in a page.. so when you get over 20 you have to keep scrolling down to select the next one.. this is why i need the page, after submitting, to jump to the last dropdown used

Comment: @brombeer As OP mentioned, the page has around 40 dropdowns so in my opinion, Ajax would be better to keep the scroll position and don't need to worry about passing additional param to form. It depends on the dev choice.

Comment: @Ravi Hirani
can you post an example? ive not worked woth ajax much so would not know were to start - thanks

Comment: @JohnDohh : It's out of scope for this post. Please post another question as and show what you have done so far and I'll definitely assist you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the action of the form to `url#your-hash` right before you submit.

```js
function change_url(form, hash) {
  form.setAttribute("action", "https://example.com/#" + hash);
  form.submit();
}

document.querySelectorAll("select").forEach(function(elem) {
  elem.addEventListener("change", function() {
    var hash = this.getAttribute("name");
    var form = this.closest("form")
    change_url(form, hash);
  })
})
```

```html
<h1>fill the form</h1>
<form action="" method="get" onsubmit="change_url(this); return false">


  <a name="sel1"></a>
  <select name="sel1">
    <option></option>
    <option>sel1</option>
  </select>

  <div style="height:500px"></div>

  <a name="sel2"></a>
  <select name="sel2">
    <option></option>
    <option>sel2</option>
  </select>

  <div style="height:500px"></div>

  <a name="sel3"></a>
  <select name="sel3">
    <option></option>
    <option>sel3</option>
  </select>

  <div style="height:500px"></div>

  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The anchor will be different for each of the dropdown menus selected.. There are, for example around 40 in a page.. so when you get over 20 you have to keep scrolling down to select the next one.. this is why i need the page, after submitting, to jump to the last dropdown used

Comment: That's an easy fix, just call change_url onchange of the select, passing the correct parameter. See me answer.

Comment: thanks for the help. I really dont understand the code you have provided so im having trouble implementing it for my needs. `var form = this.closest("form")` if my form is called "form2" should this be `var form = this.closest("form2")` I have tried changing this and it still didnt work.. Also i noticed your form has "get" were i need "post" - one last thing youare using `<a name="sel1"></a>` were i am using `id=1` and `id=2` and so on... i tried changing mine to yours but it still didnt work

Comment: Ok after some editing ive got it working so thank you IT goldman i would tag you but i dont think it works due to the spce in your name.. I had to change to this `var hash = this.getAttribute(\"id\");`  - works great :)